# Getting Null Values After "toreal" Command

Tags: qgis

I  have joined a simple CSV file to my project and am attempting to change a string value to a real value.  In editing mode, I bring up the field calculator and create a new field from the first field.  I try to change the string to real by doing the command "toreal(nameofmyfield)".  When I create the new field though, I get NULL for every value, even though I see the normal numbers in the column I am trying to change.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can not modify fields of a CSV file, because the CSV importer has limited writing ability.

Save the layer as a shapefile, and add it to the canvas. Then you can edit the fields with the field calculator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.  That makes a whole lot of sense.

What do you mean by save the layer as a shapefile?  

I ended up manually entering a column in the attribute table so I could get what I wanted (for the column to be real numbers and not a string).

Comment: If the CSV file contains coordinates, you can save it as shapefile by rghtlick on the layer name -> Save As ... For non-geographic CSV data, you can try using a csvt file as described here: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html